# Vue JS 2 on rails 5.1 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vuejs2, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I want to add VueJS to my existing rails app.

So I added these gems to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'foreman'
```

Then I ran `bundle`, `rails webpacker:install`, `rails webpacker:install:vue`, `yarn install`.

It created a `javascript` folder with: an `app.vue` file and a `packs` folder with a `hello_vue.js` file and an `application.js` file.

app/javascript/app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: "Hello Vue!"
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//
// To reference this file, add <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> to the appropriate
// layout file, like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
```

app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js

```
/* eslint no-console: 0 */
// Run this example by adding <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %> (and
// <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %> if you have styles in your component)
// to the head of your layout file,
// like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
// All it does is render <div>Hello Vue</div> at the bottom of the page.

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hello'))
  const app = new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('hello')

  console.log(app)
})


// The above code uses Vue without the compiler, which means you cannot
// use Vue to target elements in your existing html templates. You would
// need to always use single file components.
// To be able to target elements in your existing html/erb templates,
// comment out the above code and uncomment the below
// Add <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %> to your layout
// Then add this markup to your html template:
//
// <div id='hello'>
//   {{message}}
//   <app></app>
// </div>


// import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
// import App from '../app.vue'
//
// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
//   const app = new Vue({
//     el: '#hello',
//     data: {
//       message: "Can you say hello?"
//     },
//     components: { App }
//   })
// })
//
//
//
// If the using turbolinks, install 'vue-turbolinks':
//
// yarn add 'vue-turbolinks'
//
// Then uncomment the code block below:
//
// import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';
// import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
// import App from '../app.vue'
//
// Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)
//
// document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
//   const app = new Vue({
//     el: '#hello',
//     data: {
//       message: "Can you say hello?"
//     },
//     components: { App }
//   })
// })
```

I actually want to start using VueJS to build my FAQ page, so here is my faq.html.erb file (just to see if the helloworld example works):

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %>

<div id="hello container">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
 <app />
</div>;
```

I then run `foreman start`.

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/app.vue
18:26:08 frontend.1 | Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
18:26:08 frontend.1 | You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
18:26:08 frontend.1 | | <template>
18:26:08 frontend.1 | |   <div id="app">
18:26:08 frontend.1 | |     <p>{{ message }}</p>
18:26:08 frontend.1 |  @ ./app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js 9:0-29
18:26:08 frontend.1 |  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js
```

How can I properly use Vue JS on rails ?

Comment: The .vue files are not transpiled. Can you share your webpack config?

Comment: OK just found the problem ! I installed webpacker 3.1.1 but my package.json was trying to use webpacker 3.2.0. So I ran `bundle update webpacker`and re-ran the installer commands. It now works !

Comment: I think you should be seeing the app component now, but is the message working as you expected?

Comment: @ask yes thanks It works as expected. I know your tutorial and really like it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. However updating the gem did not help me.

In config/webpack/development I changed it to

```
const environment = require('./environment')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

var newPlugin = environment.toWebpackConfig();
newPlugin.plugins.push(new VueLoaderPlugin());
module.exports = newPlugin;
```

And in config/webpack/enviroment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const vue =  require('./loaders/vue')

 environment.loaders.append('vue', vue)
 environment.loaders.append('babel', {
 test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader'
 })
 module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 0):

That can happen due to vue-loader v.15 requiring VueLoaderPlugin but default webpack config doesn't have it yet.

Recent issue: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1453

For Webpacker 3 the solution is to temporarily downgrade to previous vue-loader version.

```
yarn upgrade vue-loader@14.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the vue-loader to 15.9.2 in the package.json works for me.